# How to keep history data instead of reference to updated one in mongodb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

In many cases, I need to keep the data not changed after I created. But I also need to reference to the updated information to create a new record. For example, I have two collections;

```
Order{
  has may products
}

Product{
  name: string
  price: float
}
```

When I create an order, I need to reference to the current product information and put them in the order document. But after I created the order, I do not want it changed when the product is changed later. How can I achieve this in mongodb? I should use embeds_many relationship?

Btw, I'm using mongoid in a rails app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can store both the '_id' and 'price' of referenced products into your order document. So a typical order document looks like:

```
{_id: 1, productsOrdered: [{_id: 1, price: 100, number: 2},{_id:3, price:20, number: 10},.....,{_id: 9, price:11, number:1}], .....}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually want to keep the whole snapshot of the product object.

Comment: Zou have to store the whole Object in your order or create a more sophisticated logic for the history of products. (Depends on whats changing all the time)